# Track user location through mobile number

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, geolocation, locationmanager

I want to create an application, when I enter any mobile number it should give me current location of that number.
Guys please help me if it is possible then tell me how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

you cant get the location from cell number !!!!!

though there are some applications in some countries which they do something like this but the mechanism is different.

how they work is, user registers in their app and they use Cell Number as username for registering users. then this way they can tell you the location of other users by phone number. (you can just see users' location who registered in app)

since there isnt any way to get the cell number programatically so such system you want cant exist unless the user gives you the number and you verify it some how (sending code sms and etc) and thats what the apps i mentioned are doing.